# Can shudra wear thread on waist?

Tags: dharma-shastras, smriti, shudra

Can shudra wear thread on waist ?
What  Dharma Shastra is telling that shudra can wear thread around their waist(A ceremony which is called Molathadu in Telugu)?

If not, then any sacred thread for shudra ?

Comment: Any one can wear a molathadu as the pelvic thread...a personal dressing/clothing /medical accessory used to suspend kowpeenam etc. There are no slokas,  kowpeena  thanthu paramam pavithram etc.

Comment: Yes, they can. Each group has a different Thread.

Comment: @Kumar what thread is there for shudra

Comment: @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud it depends upon the area. Some wear 2 or 3 numbers

Comment: @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud Like In some Area vaishya wear, 2 and others 3. In some it is opposite. So, You can wear whatever ever number you want.